# ¿Cómo llamar a un método de un objeto dentro de un array?

Tags: java, array

Contexto: administrador de empleados. Desde el main se llama al metodo `altaEmpleado()`. El mismo lo que hace es insertar empleados (previamente pidiendo el ingreso de parametros por teclado, como dni, nombre, sexo, etc.) y a medida que se van ingresando los empleados, se los va cargando en un array.

¿Cómo puedo llamar a un método de un empleado referenciándolo por la posición del array?

Es decir, algo asi: `array[4].tomarAgua();`

Answer (score 4):

Algo así, el `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Empleado[] empleados = new Empleado[10];
    Empleado pepe = new Empleado(1234 , "Pepe", 12);
    Empleado juan = new Empleado(1235 , "Juan", 13);
    Empleado gonzalo = new Empleado(1236 , "Gonzalo", 12);
    empleados[0] = pepe;
    empleados[1] = juan;
    empleados[2] = gonzalo;

    System.out.println(empleados[2].tomarAgua());
}
```

La clase de `Empleado`:

```
public class Empleado {

    private int dni;
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;

    public Empleado (int dni,String nombre,int edad) {
        this.dni=dni;
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.edad=edad;
    }

    public String tomarAgua() {
        return "El empleado: "+ this.nombre + " está tomando agua.";
    }
}
```

Eso anda perfecto, por lo que creo que estás teniendo problemas con el método de `altaEmpleado()`